# Reusing call back functions in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, helper

I have two Apex methods "c.getStudentGrades" and "c.getStudentAverage". They both reference the same table and use the same ID but the returned results are different. I'm trying to cut down on some repetitive code in my helper function and I'm wondering if it's possible to re-use a callback function for the two different Apex controller calls.

One idea I had was to pass the actionType in as a variable to my helper. I've tested it out and it works but I'm just wondering if it's good practice?

Controller.js

```
handleStudent: function(component, event, helper){
    var selected = event.getParam("student");
    helper.getStudent(component, selected.Id, 'c.getStudent', 0);
    helper.getStudent(component, selected.Id, 'c.getStudentAvg', 1);
}
```

Helper.js

```
getStudent : function(component, id, actionType, index){
    var action = component.get(actionType);

    action.setParams({
       "id": id
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       var state = response.getState():
       if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
          var student = response.getReturnValue();
          component.set("v.student", student);
          this.testFunction(student, index);
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little open-ended, but I would advise against passing in an array or list of parameters that rely on a specific order. It's not intuitive to use and you have to establish an arbitrary association between index 0 and 1 and 2, etc. when a map or a custom object can do the same thing while also having a more static, descriptive structure.

In your case, I wouldn't worry about repeating code - *especially* since you're just trying to consolidate two methods. Code is read more often than it's written, so coming up with a clever method that does two things is not going to be as maintainable than two methods that do two different things well. It's not clear what possible values are allowed to be passed to `getStudent` but currently `actionType` is limited to `c.getStudent` and `c.getStudentAvg` and `testIndex` to 0 and 1. So there are multiple runtime errors that can create and the only indications for acceptable values of `actionType` are written into your controller. But what if you need to add another action? How is another developer going to feel about extending this code?

If you're looking to gain efficiencies, then I would look towards why you make two subsequent calls to the Salesforce server in sequence every time you need information about a student. If grades and GPA are always needed together, then refactor your Apex code to return all of the information together rather than doing refactoring in your component (you can use a wrapper class for this). You could easily return one response that includes both grades and GPA in one call - then you could also cache that because the greatest bottlenecks in any web project (generally speaking) are time spent sending data over the network and time spent accessing data from a database.

EDIT: I would not recommend just returning a map to get both results back, but instead use a wrapper class (formally known as the adapter pattern - called such because you "adapt" the response to a format the caller is expecting. You'll find a lot of examples and documentation if you search for either). An example for your use case:

```java
// change `Object` to your respective Objects
public class StudentWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Object> gradesByQuarter { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Map<Id, Object> gradePointAverage { get; set; }
}

// assigning values, adjust to your codebase

StudentWrapper gradeInfo = new StudentWrapper();
gradeInfo.gradesByQuarter = getStudent(studentId);
gradeInfo.gradePointAverage = getStudentAvg(studentId);
```

```js
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState():
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        /** 
        *  The returned object structure:
        *
        *   {
        *       gradesByQuarter: [ ... ],
        *       gradePointAverage: { ... }
        *   }
        *
        */

        var gradeInfo = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set('v.gradesByQuarter', gradeInfo.gradesByQuarter);
        component.set('v.gradePointAverage', gradeInfo.gradePointAverage);

        // ex. accessing specific value
        console.log(gradeInfo.gradePointAverage['someKey']);
    }
}
```

In terms of Apex maps returned to JavaScript, they're synonymous with plain old JavaScript objects and you'd access them the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One apex method will return the student's average score for every quarter over the past year (as of now, this is in a List) while the other method gets an overall average of the student's grade to compare it.

I will look into refactoring my apex and possibly return a map instead. Can you recommend a resource for me to use a returned Apex map in my Javascript?

Comment: See my edits. You will need to adjust to match your existing code.

Comment: You should be able to accept my answer 

Comment: Done, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In Apex you can fetch the data from both the methods and add it to a wrapper.

```
public class TestWrapper{        
    @AuraEnabled public FirstWrapper firstWrapper {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled public SecondWrapper secondWrapper {get; set;}
}
```

With one call from UI populate both data in the wrapper and pass that to UI.

Also you can remove `component.isValid()` as salesforce internally handles that.

Comment: Thanks, I think the only issue with this is, my method "getStudentGrades" returns a list and "getStudentAverage" returns a Map